# Is custom views context always an Activity?

Tags: android, android-context

I have a custom View that will be inflated from xml and has some custom xml attributes.

This view would setup some things in the ActionBar, if a xml attribute has been set to true.
Therefore I need a reference to the activities action bar.

My question is:
Can I assume that the context passed in the constructor of

```
class MyView extends View {
    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){

         Activity a = (Activity) context;

    }
}
```

I have tested that with different devices and different android versions, and it seems t that the context is an Activity.

Does anybody know that for sure?

Comment: yes its an activity context.

Comment: Also if I inflate my custom view from an LayoutInflater programmaticaly like getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); ?

Comment: you need a activity context for that.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

No. If you theme the layout containing your view you will end up with a `ContextThemeWrapper`.